# Multiple spring task executors with annotation-driven spring tasks

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks, spring-annotations

I have a class `MessageProcessor` being called by another method in another class (i.e. Caller).

```
public class Caller {
@Scheduled(filxedDelay=10)
public void poll(){
//do stuff
messageProcessor.process(msg);
}

}

public class MessageProcessor{

@Async(value="abcExecutor")
public void process(String msg){
//do stuff here.
}

}
```

Spring file looks like:

```
<task:executor id="abcExecutor" pool-size="9" rejection-policy-"CALLER_RUNS"/>
```

I want to add another @Async executor:

```
 @Async(value="defExecutor")
    public void remove(String msg){
    //do stuff here.
    }

@Scheduled(filxedDelay=10)
public void kill(){
//do stuff
messageProcessor.remove(msg);
}
```

By adding another executor in spring file:

```
<task:executor id="defExecutor" pool-size="9" rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS"/>
```

But how to add multiple executors in `<task:annotation-driven executor="abcExecutor" scheduler="scheduler" mode="proxy" proxy-target-class="true"/>`

How can I make these multiple executors run with annotation?

**PS**: Obviously, I don't want to have the same pool being used for both the
   `@Async` methods

Comment: It should work by specifying the `value` of @Async. No need to specify it in the xml. Have you tried it and see which executor is used?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `@Async("defExecutor")` is sufficient to designate the method to be handled by the 2nd executor. The xml declaration specifies only the default executor, which will be used whenever no value is specified in `@Async`.

See the [explanation of Chris Beams](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-6847?focusedCommentId=79096&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#comment-79096) in [this issue](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-6847):

Comment: I cannot try for now but will it get handled by the thread pool mentioned in the xml (i.e. 9 threads)?

Comment: both pools are 9 threads, so I don't know which are you referring to :) but it will be handled either by the executor you specify, or by the default

Comment: What about `@Scheduled` annotations? Is there a way to specify executor for it?

Answer (score -2):

So, is it a right XML ?

```
<task:executor id="abcExecutor" pool-size="9" rejection-policy-"CALLER_RUNS"/>
<task:executor id="defExecutor" pool-size="9" rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS"/>
<task:annotation-driven executor="abcExecutor" scheduler="scheduler" mode="proxy" proxy-target-class="true"/>
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?